# How do you unit test for tcp connection?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, tcp

I've recently been given a chance to write a simple tcp-client for a project of mine, and due to my huge ignorance with tcp/ip, I have a hard time getting it to work properly.

I find that sometimes I can get weird connection issue when the connection refused as the tcp server is down or sometimes I might get an exception when calling receive.

As the tcp-server is a black box and we have no access to it, I'm wondering in this situation, what's the best way to write unit tests for this?

I'm thinking either I should write a tcp-server and make it return certain inputs as what I would expect from the real server or just mock the functions related to return ideal situation data.

I just don't like the fact that sometimes I might get weird connection/receive issue and I would like to know how to properly write unit test which I can reuse/extend in the future to ensure that everything that work before should still be working in case my code or their code change.

thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should have two kinds of tests:

1. **Integration tests** - with real bare-bone TCP server that can send and
   receive connections. Create this server that has the bare minimum
   functionality and use it to test how your client behaves. Using a
   simple TCP server you can test how your client send and receive
   messages and how it connects and disconnect from the server. Another
   useful test is how several clients connect and send messages to the
   server.
2. **Unit tests** - using Mocking you can test more complex scenarios. You
   won't be able to send or receive messages but you can test the
   client's internal logic - how it behaves if two messages with
   arrive, re-sending in case of errors etc.

Using both kinds of tests you should be able to cover most of your client's functioanlity

Comment: Yup, i think you're right, i guess i kept thinking that unit test are supposed to be small and not dependent on anything. But i forgot to ask myself what am i trying to test? and i'm trying to test the behavior of the other system's tcp server then i would just have to write integration type unit test for them.

Answer (score 2):

For unit testing, I'd create a simple socket server (kicked off when the UT starts) just for the purpose of testing the client.  If you make it simple and standalone you'll reduce hassles running the test.  You may also be able to use tools like ncat to facilitate this.

However having said that there may be problems that might be harder for the UT to pick up.  Keepalive issues, maybe external problems such as routing.  But if you use a real listening socket (as opposed to mocking a connection) it's real TCP.

Comment: Such tests are not **unit tests** but rather so-called **integration tests**. Unit tests do not involve any network connection but rather they mock them out testing just the _unit_.

Comment: I disagree; it's still a unit test as long as the tcp connection and server is completely *self contained*.  However if it does require external support (such as having to launch an http server) it's no longer a unit test.

Comment: I see unit tests as testing a single "unit" of code's input/output. Input/output can come in the function's arguments and return value, and it can come by using an external interface (receiving "input" from it and supplying "output" to it).

As long as you don't use other "units" of your own code, creating and supplying a "mock" of the external interfaces is still unit testing (you are still testing a single unit). Creating a dummy server socket is the same as supplying input via arguments and retrieving output via a return value.